# Animating content loaded with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

that i don't know if it's even possible. I wanna try to load content with Ajax, and animate it right away, piece by piece. I have empty body. And on server side i have document with with h1 paragraph and two images. I wanna load them with ajax with animation from different angles (left, top, right, bottom). I know how to animate but as soon as i load them they are already on the page and i want to animate them into the page. Code looks like this:

```
<body>
<button id="load"></button>
</body>
```

My jquery script

```
 <script>
    $('#load').click(function() {
        callAjax();
        return false;

    });// end of click function 

});

function callAjax() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: 'content.html',
         success: function(data){
         if(data !== ""){
          $("html").prepend(data);
          }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error', data);
        },
        complete: function () {
        console.log("done");        }
    }); //ajax call

} //document ready
</script>
```

server side data

```
<section class="content">
<h1>About</h1>
<p> Text</p>
<img src="ipad.png" class="rotate">
<img src="ipad1.png" class="circle">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide 'data' and then animate it in.

```
$(data).hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

To animate the elements you'd need more than 1 key frame. Currently you only have 1: the end-state.  You'd need another one to animate from. Think of a move: to have a character walk on screen you'd have to position them off-screen first.

I'm going to assume we're doing just that: loading your content off-screen, then walking it on-screen.

Set the position for the elements (via CSS, or explicitly, but do so in the original file) off-screen.  For example, use this CSS:

```
position: absolute;
left: -1000;
```

which would place the element 1000 pixels to the left of the window.  That's your starting position, which is where you're going to "start" at after you have loaded the content (asynchronously).

The next part is the transition phase moving them from START to END via a series of intermediate steps computed by your code. There are many robust JS/HTML/CSS/SVG animation libraries, but I'm going to use a basic JS function: setInterval.

```
var thing = $('#yourThing'); // select your thing
var distInterval = 1000 / 60; // we're going to move 1000px every 60 steps
var code = function() { 
  thing.position().left = thing.position().left + distInterval; // move by the distance
  // destination is an abs position of 100px from the left
  if (thing.position().left == 100) {
    window.clearInterval(); // stops the loop
  }
};
var delay: 16.7; // 1/60th of a second, in ms
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay); // set and start the loop
```

Once you are comfortable with this concept you'll soon find that this is a poor implementation choice. Some keywords to google for will be the "requestAnimationFrame()" function and the term "easings".